# Python: redirect_stdout doesn't catch logger

Tags: python, logging, stdout

I'm trying to redirect some logging output.

```
import sys
import logging
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout)
logger = logging.getLogger()

with open("out.txt", "w") as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        print("STDOUT")
        logger.warning("LOGGER")
```

I would expect both of these to output to `out.txt` but instead `STDOUT` goes to the file, and `WARNING:root:LOGGER` displays in the terminal.

I've confirmed that that logger *is* outputting to `stdout` by removing the redirect stuff and running `python script.py > stdout.txt`. Then everything gets to the file, as it should.

So the `logger` must be doing something weird that causes it to not get pick up by `redirect_stdout`?

(Note: The behaviour is the same with `redirect_stderr`).